# iOS scaled mode vs autolayout?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I've developed several iOS apps but never used auto layout when dealing with screen larger than 4 inch (iPhone 6 and 6+). What I did is to enable scaled mode (by deleting launch xib and adding launch image) and only layout views in 4 inch. Since they have same aspect ratio this could work.

But I'm wondering is there any drawbacks of using scaled mode instead of auto layout, or is there any particular reason to use auto-layout? 
Since I think auto layout just too much work to do and I just want all the screens have same UI (i.e. the larger the screen, the larger the view, instead of keep the view size constant but more gaps)

Answer (score 0):

Auto Layout is the future.  If Apple comes out with a new iPad that's much bigger, do you want your app to be "scaled", or take advantage of the whole screen?  Users will give you better reviews and be happier if your app is not scaled.

Auto Layout really isn't too much work.  It's more work **not** to implement it, and you shut yourself out from features like Adaptive UI, and having one code base that runs on all their devices, present or possibly future.